# How to wait the end of an Action Creator?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I use redux for dispatch an action creator (AC).

In this AC, I fetch some data to an external API (Melissa) with redux-thunk.

This AC works fine but if I try to capture this data that is set by the reducer in the store just after the call of the AC, this  value is not already set.

How I can wait that my AC is finish to exucute the next line of my code ?

My AC is :

```
export function fetchMellisa (value) {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.get( /*URL*/ )
            .then( ({ data }) => {
                dispatch( { type: ACTION_CREATOR_1 , payload: data }
                )
            } ).catch( error => console.error( 'error', error ) );
    };
}
```

and my call:

```
this.props.dispatch(fetchMellisa(values.currentAddress));
const currentAddress = this.props.addressMelissa[ 0 ].Address ;
```

this.props.addressMelissa[0].Address is my value set on the store by the reducer.

Comment: Where do you want to capture that data exactly?

Comment: the call is done in  my react component but outside of my render()

Comment: Then, this call updates the global state right? How do you capture the data? If your state is being updated properly you should get the data without any problem. Maybe seeing some more of your components,code might be useful who wants to help beside the given answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the component should re-render with the new data in props, the api call should be in a lifecycle method such as `componentDidMount` or in an event handler. if you needed to use it inline, then you should return the `axios.get` and chain a `.then` on your original dispatch.

```
export function fetchMellisa (value) {
return dispatch => {
    return axios.get( /*URL*/ )
        .then( ({ data }) => {
            dispatch( { type: ACTION_CREATOR_1 , payload: data }
            )
        } ).catch( error => console.error( 'error', error ) );
  };
}

this.startLoadingMellisa();
this.props.dispatch(fetchMellisa(values.currentAddress))
  .then( response => {
    this.stopLoadingMellisa();
    // do something that releases the loading state
  })

if ( this.state.loading ) { return <SomeLoadingComponentOrMsg/> }
const currentAddress = this.props.addressMelissa[ 0 ].Address ;
```

i didn't create everything to save time but i think there is enough here to give a good picture.

Comment: Good idea it is a best pratice. I think my problem it is the time between the AC r is launch and the time where the reducer store the value. So here, my promise is resolve because the AC  is launched but it is not store by the reducer.

Comment: i think what you need is a loading state, depending on the UI, you can either set a loading property on state before the request and then end it when the request completes, i put some edits to show this better

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your thunk to return a Promise. This is a good rule to enforce on your thunks.

```js
export function fetchMellisa(url) {
  return dispatch =>
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(({ data }) => dispatch({ type: ACTION_CREATOR_1, payload: data }))
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("error", error);
        return Promise.reject();
      });
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```js
const url = values.currentAddress;
this.props.dispatch(fetchMellisa(url)).then(() => {
  const newAddress = this.props.addressMelissa[0].Address;
});
```